# Variable-length lookbehind for backslashes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

What seemed to be a simple task ended up to not work as expected...

I'm trying to match `\$\w+\b`, unless it's preceded by an uneven number of backslashes.

Examples (only $result should be in the match):

`This $result should be matched`

`This \$result should not be matched`

`This \\$result should be matched`

`This \\\$result should not be matched`

etc...

The following pattern works:

```
(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\$\w+\b
```

However, even repeats of backslashes are included in the match, which is unwanted, so I'm trying to achieve this purely with a variable-length lookbehind, but nothing I tried so far seems to work.

Any regex virtuoso here can lend a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?<!(?:^|[^\\])\\(?:\\\\)*)\$\w+\b
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%28%3F%3A%5E%7C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%29%5C%5C%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%5C%5C%29*%29%5C%24%5Cw%2B%5Cb&i=This%20%24result%20should%20be%20matched%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%20%5C%24result%20should%20not%20be%20matched%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%20%5C%5C%24result%20should%20be%20matched%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%20%5C%5C%5C%24result%20should%20not%20be%20matched%0D%0A%0D%0A&o=m)**.

**Breakdown of the Lookbehind**; i.e., not preceded by:

- `(?:^|[^\\])` - Beginning of string/line or any character other than backslash.
- `\\` - Then, one backslash character.
- `(?:\\\\)*` Then, any even number of backslash characters (including zero).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like asking the question helped me answer my own question.

The part I don't want to be matched has to be wrapped with a **positive** lookbehind.

`(?<=(?<!\\)(\\\\)*)\$\w+\b`

Also works if the $result is at the start of the line.

If anyone has more optimal solutions, shoot!

Comment: Note that you could still use a _nagative_ Lookbehind. One variation is the one shown in my answer above. Or you could use nested Lookbehinds (like you did here): `(?<!(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*)\$\w+\b`.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression gets the wanted text in the third capture group:
`(^| )(\\\\)*(\$\w+\b)`

Explanation:

```
(^| )          Either beginning of line or a space
(\\\\)*        An even number of backslash characters, including none
(              Start of capture group 3
    \$\w+\b    The wanted text
)              End of capture group 3
```

Comment: That's also possible with the example I mentioned in the question, it wasn't a problem at all, the question was how to do that without having anything extra in the match, which was solved by my own answer and 41686d6564's answer. Thanks for the reply nevertheless.